# Automate standard Mahout recommender

Tags: hadoop, aws-lambda, amazon-emr, mahout-recommender

I'm considerably new to Mahout/Hadoop environment, so apologies if this question is trivial, however I haven't found any straightforward answer yet.

There is an EMR cluster with Mahout, where I can submit the following stardard recommender job:

```
mahout recommenditembased --input s3a://input-bucket/ratings_small.csv 
--output s3a://output-bucket/out/ --numRecommendations 2 
--similarityClassname SIMILARITY_COSINE
```

Everything is good, but it requires me being connected via SSH to the master node.

Now I'm thinking of automating this execution, so that a dedicated Lambda function submits a step to EMR and forgets about it. What could be the easiest way of doing that? Is it possible to submit it as a JAR step for Hadoop without writing the whole recommendation application in Java?

**------ UPDATED 04/10/2016 ------**

After digging into a little bit longer, the easiest option (at least for me) turned out to be a "Custom JAR" job on EMR cluster with the following parameters:

1. Name: arbitrary step name
2. JAR location: `/usr/lib/mahout/mahout-mr-0.12.2-job.jar`
3. Arguments:

   ```
   org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob 
   --input s3a://your-bucket/input/ 
   --output s3a://your-bucket/output/ 
   --similarityClassname SIMILARITY_EUCLIDEAN_DISTANCE 
   --tempDir temp/random_guid/
   ```
4. Action on failure - Continue.

Obviously, you can also submit the job above completely programmatically via AWS CLI or SDK.

**Note:** I used `--tempDir` in arguments, because every time when the recommender is executed, Mahout creates a temporary directory in HDFS (by default, it is `temp/`). However, Mahout *does not* delete that directory once the calculations are finished. Therefore, if you submit 2 consecutive recommender jobs, the second one will fail with an error similar to

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory temp/preparePreferenceMatrix/itemIDIndex already exists
```

As I submit recommender jobs programmatically, I've decided to use different temporary directory with a random guid for every job. Alternatively, you can manually remove a temporary directory, which was created by the previous job, before submitting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to use EMR data pipeline template which is pretty much for automation.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on whether this cluster would remain up and around for awhile?  AWS Data Pipeline is really designed for a single use cluster.  It doesn't really work out that well for long-running clusters that need to schedule the job to run on a regular interval.

If you want this to run on regularly, then you might consider using a regular EMR cluster and then use Oozie to schedule your job.  Here you would need to create a jar with all of your Mahout stuff in it.

Finally, if you find that you want to shrink and expand your cluster for bigger and smaller jobs, you can use a resizing tool that will let you do just that with an EMR cluster, which does not support autoscaling out of the box, check out this article

http://www.lopakalogic.com/articles/hadoop-articles/dynamically-resize-emr/

The source code is available on Github, link in the article.